# Open Facebook group page using Facebook app on IOS

Tags: ios, facebook

In my IOS app, I want to open facebook app to a GROUP.

On Android, I simply opened the following URL:

"fb://group/12345678/" (I replaced the group id for this example)

This worked fine on android. When trying the same thing in IOS:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://group/12345678/"]];
```

Facebook app opens but I get:

"The link you followed may have been broken, or the page may have been removed."

I can't find any other ways to open to a public facebook group from IOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using "profile" instead of "group" (e.g. `URLWithString:@"fb://profile/144754840"`).

Comment: This simply loads a completely blank page in the Facebook app.

Answer (score 1):

You can user **page** with **id**, like this:

ObjC

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/?id=12345678"]
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Swift3

```
func openFBGroup(groupID: String = "12345678") -> Bool {
    guard let url = URL(string: "fb://page/?id=\(groupID)") else { return false }
    guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else { return false }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [], completionHandler: nil)
    return true
}
```

Swift4

```
@discardableResult func openFBGroup(groupID: String = "12345678") -> Bool {
    guard let url = URL(string: "fb://page/?id=\(groupID)") else { return false }
    guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else { return false }
    return UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: How do i find fb groupID ?

Comment: @dip it's in URL of the group. check numbers at the end

Comment: I had to use "fb://group/?id=<id>" to get the desired result (**2021, Swift 5**).

Answer (score 0):

To open group in facebook app you just need open full url:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/gropId"]
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Instead `https://fb.com/gropId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use profile and group ID to open Facebook group in facebook app, detail code:

```
NSURL *facebookGroupURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/123456/"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookGroupURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookGroupURL];
}
else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/groups/123456/"]];
}
```

Browse:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7iYO.png)

Mobile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwixQ.png)

It works for me on Xcode 9.1/iOS 11.1.2